# How to update UI in swift from a method

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am new to swift, I am writing an app which needs to change images in the storyboard. i have written a function to change images in the image view. In the function there is an if condition the image should be changed when the if condition is satisfied, but i got "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value" error when if condition is executed.

```
   import UIKit
   import MessageUI
   import Foundation
   import CoreLocation
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var F_IMG: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet var FL_IMG: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet var FR_IMG: UIImageView!


   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    TimeService.initial(viewcontroller: self)

    }

    public func showImages(){

       var type: String = Otherclass.gettype()

      setImageForType(type:type)


      }


      public  func setImageForType(type:String){

        if (type == "NONE"){

              DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.F_IMG.image = UIImage(named: "r_f")

        }
```

"The showImage() function is called in another class."

I have the image in the bundle, but my UI is not getting updated and it always shows the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value"

Comment: check once your property of FrontImg

Comment: And please, tell us in which exact line the crash occurs

Comment: Yes, do tell us exact line where crash occurs.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - The FrontIMg is nil

Comment: Go through my answer again, if it still does not work then show how you have initialised FrontImg.

Comment: So you're calling showImages() from other class. Try replacing self.F_IMG.image to ViewController.F_IMG.image & let me know if it works.

Comment: @ArpitDongre - No it is still crashing

Comment: Okay, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `FrontImg` is properly connected to *Storyboard* or correctly initialised through code.

**Update:**

As it turns out, you're calling `showImages()` from other class, hence it is giving nil error.

By calling `ViewController.showImages()` from other class, you are creating a new **ViewController**, not referencing an existing one. This new one doesn't have a `F_IMG(imageView)` yet because its view hasn't been built. You reference self.F_IMG.image is nil.

My advice is to use `NSNotificationCenter` for updating UI in other View Controller.

For more approaches, refer this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32175143/5620628)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem was caused in this line :

```
self.FrontImg.image = UIImage(named: "r_f")
```

If you check the [Apple Docs on UIImage class](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init), the initializer you are using `init?(named name: String)` actually returns **optional**.

So, have you tried

```
self.FrontImg.image = UIImage(named: "r_f")!
```

Comment: Still it is crashing

Answer (score 0):

The only thing here which I have found to make sure your UIElement `FrontImg` must be connected properly.

Comment: How does it help?

Comment: I have added the explanation, hope it will help you.

Comment: I am aware of the concept of Optionals in Swift, I'm just curious how does it help to add "!" ahead of FrontImg. If it needed force unwrap, it wouldn't have complied in the first place.

Comment: As the error tells as it's nil so we have to make optional so that we added, is that make sense?

Comment: No, it still does not make any sense to me at least.

Comment: It simply wouldn't have compiled if FrontImg needed an "!". The nil error is most probably because either FrontImg isn't connected to Storyboard properly or he left some value nil.

Comment: As probably this is FrontImage IBOutlet connection, so error will have chance to unconnected UIElement object usage. so marking to option will make safer. now make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129562/discussion-between-arpit-dongre-and-sandy).